# How to execute commands during S2I build in Openshift?

Tags: openshift, s2i

Openshift CLI command to start S2I (source to image) build looks like this:

`oc start-build buildname --from-dir=./someDirectory--wait=true`

But how can we execute some shell command? `os start-build` is going to create image (described in the build definition) and copy `someDirectory` to it, but what if we need additional configuration of that image, not only to push compiled source code there?

Answer (score 1):

There're a couple of options:

- Provide a layer in the Dockerfile
- Override assemble script

assemble script override options:

- Provide *.s2i/bin/assemble* into the code repository
- Specify *spec.strategy.sourceStrategy.scripts* in the BuildConfig with URL of a directory containing the scripts (see [override builder image scripts](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/builds/build_strategies.html#override-builder-image-scripts))

Example of assemble script and s2i workflow you can check in [s2i](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/creating_images/s2i.html) or there's simple example:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Run additional build before steps

# Execute original assemble script.
/usr/libexec/s2i/assemble

# Run additional build after steps
```

In addition, There's postCommit [build hooks](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/builds/build_hooks.html) which executes after commiting the image and before pushing it to the registry. It executes in temporary container so it can only be used to do some tests.